# Alternative to Mailgun that can do routing/forwarding of incoming emails based on regex matching

Tags: email

After many years with Mailgun setup as as MX for our domains (to receive emails and forward them on based on complex regex rules), in the past two weeks or so we have experienced very long delays and failures with Mailgun processing forwarding rules; emails are received fine by Mailgun, but then their servers get stuck processing the forwarding rules. Lately they also had problems in delivering emails. To their credit, Mailgun has admitted they have been having issues and we've been patient, but it's gotten worse in the past week and it impedes our tasks, e.g. some emails contain codes that expire after 30 minutes, which affects our work. I wish we could afford to keep waiting and tolerate this but we can't.

I've looked around and found plenty of cloud email services, but their descriptions are *not* clear to say whether it can be setup as MX for own domains *and* allow regex based inbound email forwarding. Many (most?) of them are send-only and can't also receive.

I signed up and tried a few (Sendgrid, Elqastic email, Mailchimp, Sparkpost) and it's quite time consuming.

I'd be really grateful for suggestions of tried and tested (and preferably 2+ years on the market) cloud email services that have the following minimal features

- set it up as MX for multiple own domains, say. domain1.com, domain2.com, so it can receive emails
- allow setting up up regex rules to match on various email headers in order to intercept incoming emails sent to @domain1.com and @domain2.com and forward them to arbitrary other email addresses such as foo@abc.com
- allow manual SMTP, using both API and direct SMTP, so i can email through it using both standard email clients and programmatically (this is pretty standard for most of them as far as I've seen)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend [ZoneEdit.com](https://zoneedit.com), they have what they call `mailmaps`, and they have a free option.

I'm not sure the matching is RegEx, but I'm sure (because I use it) it can handle wildcards.